# Google Maps API click url event not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created some markers on google maps and want to open the country's php page when I click on it(marker) but I don't know why it doesn't do that. Here is the layout of my code:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var germany = {lat: 51.268917, lng:  9.591616};
    var russia = {lat: 55.765237, lng: 37.582553};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: germany
    });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: germany,
      map: map,
      title:'Germany',
      url:'Germany.php',
      animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: russia,
      map: map,
      title:'Russia',
      animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
   {window.location.href = marker.url;});
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=My_API_Key&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually add comments, but you can try this. I have working for mine. You can tidy it up too.

```
    <script>
  function callMyUrl(element){
    alert('I am from ' + element.title);
  }

  function initMap() {
    var germany = {lat: 51.268917, lng:  9.591616};
    var russia = {lat: 55.765237, lng: 37.582553};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: germany
    });

var location = [
  {title: 'Germany', lat: 51.268917, lng:  9.591616 },
  {title: 'Russia', lat: 55.765237, lng: 37.582553 }
]

  location.forEach(function(element){
    var marker;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng),
      title: element.title,
      map: map
    });
    return google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      callMyUrl(element);
    });
  });
}
</script>
```